# Routing issue in nopCommerce 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 2.2. I am having an issue in URL routing, explained below

I want to use following route.

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Product",
                       "{region}/{bookTitle}-{isbn}",
                       new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Product" },
                       new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

So, the URL should look like this.
http://localhost:3129/us/303-tips-for-successful-12345

But unfortunately I am getting error

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /303-tips-for-successful-12345

---

In above URL ("/303-tips-for-successful-12345"), the first segment "us" is missing ..

If I use following route in route provider(added static segment "p"),

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Product",
                       "p/{region}/{bookTitle}-{isbn}",
                       new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Product" },
                       new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

I will get perfect URL without any error.

```
http://localhost:3129/p/us/303-tips-for-successful-12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route matches the standard {Controller}/{Action} one in form.  The routing engine has no way to know if /us is a Controller or a Region.

Comment: Yes that's true but my standard pattern is {Controller}/{Action}/{id} which is different from the new one {region}/{bookTitle}-{isbn} here there is a '-' between second and third segment. and standard pattern is added to route collection after new pattern is added ...